# First update ignored when updating modle asynchronously in AngularJS ng-click handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is how I intend my application to work:

**When a button get clicked, an HTTP request is sent to get more items, and the returned item
array will be appended to existing ones in the model.**

So I set `ng-click` of the button to be an expression in which a function is called to request more items.

But it doesn't work as I expected, the first click updated the model correctly, but the items list in the UI didn't reflect the change.

I suspect that this is because the requesting process is asynchronous, so I set up the following experiment:

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app  ng-controller="ItemController">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-click="append()">Duplicate Items!</button>
</div>
```

**JS(Synchronous)**

```
function ItemController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1, 2, 3];

    $scope.append = function () {
        $scope.items = $scope.items.concat($scope.items);
    };
}
```

**JS(asynchronously)**

```
function ItemController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1, 2];

    $scope.append = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.items = $scope.items.concat($scope.items);
            console.log($scope.items);
        }, 500);
    };
}
```

**jsfiddle links**

- sync: http://jsfiddle.net/zjVd6/
- async: http://jsfiddle.net/aMMzQ/

It turns out that the synchronous version works correctly, and asynchronous one fails like my application.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing `setTimeout` with `$timeout` ([http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout)), which updates the listeners correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/6tUKM/

```
function ItemController($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = [1, 2, 3];

    $scope.append = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.items = $scope.items.concat($scope.items);
            console.log($scope.items);
        }, 500);
    };
}
```

or you can do this manually:

```
$scope.append = function () {
    var f = function () {
        $scope.items = $scope.items.concat($scope.items);
        console.log($scope.items);
    };
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(f)
    }, 500);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. But I still don't quite understand why built-in async functions like `setTimeout` won't work, do you happen to know the reason?

Comment: they work, it is just that Angular does not know that the scope was updated from outside. you need to let it know by calling `$apply`. Here is a good article: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html